# Missing Assembly Reference for OfficeMergeControlException

Tags: c#

When I try to use the code to combine multiple .docx files (the first listing at: [Append multiple DOCX files together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247666/how-can-i-programatically-use-c-sharp-to-append-multiple-docx-files-together)), I seem to be missing an assembly reference for OfficeMergeControlException.

I'm using .NET Framework 4.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 1):

There is no point throwing a custom Exception in that scenerio. Just throw an Exception

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Error while merging files. Document index {0}", pointer), e);
}
```

Or better yet dont catch an exception at all. You are losing information by changing the exception type and formatting a message.

Comment: @Rich  when u get a correct answer you should mark it as correct by clicking the tick below the up down arrows

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a custom exception. Something like:

```
public class OfficeMergeControlException : Exception 
{
    public OfficeMergeControlException(string message, System.Exception innerException)  : base(message, innerException) { }
}
```