# merge multiple docx files into a single docx file

Tags: openxml

I came across solutions on how to merge docx files using c#:

[Append multiple DOCX files together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247666/how-can-i-programatically-use-c-sharp-to-append-multiple-docx-files-together)

In this solution, he iterates through files and copies the body "outerxml" to a new document:

```
XElement tempBody = XElement.Parse(tempDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.OuterXml);
newBody.Add(tempBody);
```

This looks somethign specific to c# api. But I am using Ruby. So far I have been able to edit the docx file and make changes to it by editing  "word/document.xml". However, now I need to merge multiple docx files, and I would like to know if there is a specific xml file in openxml that encompasses an entire document, so that I can use that to copy into another document.

Answer (score 1):

The main document part (usually at word/document.xml) contains the text of the body of the docx.  Headers/footers/comments/footnotes/endnotes are elsewhere.

The problem is that the main document part will often refer to other parts, and you need to manage these references.

Some of these references (eg images, headers, footers) are via "relationships" in the rels part; others are styles, comment ids etc.

If your documents are predictable and simple, you could handle those cases yourself. Otherwise, you'd be better of using http://openxmldeveloper.org/wiki/w/wiki/documentbuilder.aspx (C#) or our commercial [MergeDocx](http://www.plutext.com/m/index.php/products) component (Java).